# How do i monitor a directory creation on linux using ruby and get notified via email

Tags: ruby, file, monitoring

so lets say i have a pre existing directories /source/version/1 , /source/version/2, /source/version/3
I want to monitor if there is a NEW directory created /source/version/4, and send an email if such directory is indeed created.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel subsystem that allows an application to receive notifications of file system changes, such as directory creation, is called [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). There is a [Ruby interface to inotify](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-inotify/), but there doesn't seem to be much documentation available for it.

[kfsmd](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/124903) is a daemon for monitoring file system changes (using inotify). It has a client that produces output to the console whenever a change occurs. You could pipe this output into your Ruby script and parse it.